# ASP.NET using Button instead of FileUpload to upload files

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to upload a file with `Button` element using hidden `FileUpload` element with `ASP.NET` using this snippet:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + FileUpload1.ClientID + "').click();");
}
```

My Button has `Id = "Button2"`, FileUpload `Id = "FileUpload1"`. Clicking on the button Windows Explorer opens successfully to upload files but `FileUpload.HasFile` still returns false in further code (no file gets loaded even though explorer gets opened and file is selected).

What is the cause of this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you want to hide the the `FileUpload` Control and still be able to upload the files.

Follow the following steps to achieve the required:

1. Place a `FileUpload` Control with the class hidden. Like below:

```
<style>
    .hidden{
      display: none;
    }
</style>
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1" CssClass="hidden" />
```

2. Then place a Button that will be visible to client and will handle the `Javascript` events

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Upload File" OnClick="Button1_Clicked" />
```

3. Add the `Javascript` events to handle things

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // This event will help click the FileUpload control
    $('#<%= Button1.ClientID %>').on('click', function(){
        $('#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>').click();
        return false; // important to return false, so it does not posts back yet.
    });

    $('#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>').on('change', function(){ // To see if the file selection was changed and the user has selected something
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            alert('No file selected');
            return false;
        }
        if(confirm('Do you want to upload this file? ' + $(this).val())){
            __doPostBack('<%= Button1.ClientID %>', ''); // this will postback to the server click event
        }
    });

});
```

4. Now, handle the uploaded file.

```
public void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Handle your upload function
    var hasFile = FileUpload1.HasFile;
}
```

**PS:** It was a rough Idea, the code is not tested so it might need some love.